# Is there a file size limit to what the data link can store?

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-processing

For example, an image, video or sound file can be stored in the data link

In this case, an image can be stored with the starting link: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/.....` followed by many characters. However, is there a certain file size limit in which the data link cannot be capable of holding and storing it?

In my case, a user can upload an image to my site which is then sent through a server socket so others can view that image. But once uploaded, the image data link is stored within their localStorage, then emitted to the server side socket. However, there is a limit of storing `5mb` within a localStorage. This then results to the user having to upload or use an image under the capable limit of localStorage. I am questioning if it is possible to just simply store the image link within a variable, as the image only needs to be sent so others can see it, it is not stored within a database.

This is my current code of storing the image from the input link they can upload the image from:

```
var image = e.target.result

localStorage.uploadedImage = imgto
```

Then sends the image through the socket:

```
socket.emit('<img style="border-radius: 4px; width: 16rem" src="${localStorage.uploadedImage}">`);
```

Is there a limit to how much the link can store of an image, no matter the quality or file size?

Comment: What is a "data link"? Are you talking about a [data:// URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)? Why are you storing this image in the LocalStorage? The Storage API is not meant to store binary data, IndexedDB is.

Comment: yes, I don't know what it's called

Comment: Then, no, there is no limit per se, though the thing that will use these URIs may very well have limits. For instance V8's string are limited to 512MB, some browsers have limits to what can be set in the address bar etc.

Comment: Im just using the data://URL in the <img> tag, so there is no limit to that?

Comment: kinda odd having a video or sound file in an img-tag?

Comment: Well yes, if you set this url through js, you'll face V8's limit I talked about (but a 512MB image is already a big image ;-)) But in your code you are going through LocalStorage, which in most browsers is limited to something like 5MB IIRC, that will be your first issue. And if the image is from an <input> then use a [`blob:// URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) you'll save a lot of memory.

Comment: tip, emit the blob not a string (which is open to XSS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried about storage limits on the client side then use a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) to store the image. The blob storage system in Google Chrome allows for Gigabytes to be stored in a blob, I would imagine that the other browsers have a similar capacity although I have never had reason to investigate such limits. See [Chrome's Blob Storage System Design](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/224e43ce1ca4f6ca6f2cd8d677b8684f4b7c2351/storage/browser/blob/README.md) for details of Google's implementation.